# HTML5 video timeupdate event not firing

Tags: javascript, events, video, html5-video

I do have a `<video>` element on my page:

```
<video id="myVideo">
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="vid.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

In my JS it reads:

```
var v = $('#myVideo')[0];
v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
   alert('I changed');
},false);
```

Now I will fire up my console and type:

```
$('#myVideo')[0].currentTime = 2;
```

The displayed frame will change, yet the event will not fire. According to the specs `timeupdate` should fire when `currentTime was changed`, so I do not think I am using the wrong event? All other events I am using (i.e. `play` & `ended`) are working just fine.

There are a lot of similar questions out there, yet all of those seem to be outdated bugs? Is this yet another bug (I tested in Chrome 17 and FF10) or did anything change in the event structure? Or am I missing something completely different?

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that this problem will only occur when the video has not yet played. So when I do:

```
$('#myVideo')[0].play();
$('#myVideo')[0].pause();
$('#myVideo')[0].currentTime = 2;
```

The event will fire just like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as already stated in the edit to my question I solved this with a simple and rather stupid  approach. Just do:

```
video.play();
video.pause();
```

to "initialize" the playhead. Then one should be able to get `timeupdate` events even if no one ever started the video.

On a side note: strangely, setting `preload` to `auto` does trigger a preload of the video, yet it does not seem to initialize the playhead.

Answer (score 2):

the event is only dispatched after the video has been initialized. like you just pointed out in your edit-comment, where you play() and pause() the video, which preloads the video. same should happen, if you use the preload attribute with auto (auto = author thinks that the browser should load the entire video when the page loads)

```
<video preload="auto|metadata|none">
```

but i guess you answered your question yourself?!

Comment: So there's no way to detect if a video's playhead has been moved before the video has been started for the first time?

Comment: maybe we re talking at cross purposes, but how can you seek a video, which hasn't been loaded (or is loading) already? are your controls shown all the time? do you have a short example for that case?! ..maybe this site helps too:http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html list of all events in a live example. seeked might be your attribute?!

Comment: This might be a little complicated, yet see: http://goo.gl/uJyod - you may want to unhide the `<video>` element to see what happens. Type `$('#video')[0].currentTime = 1;` into the console and the video will update, yet the canvas representation won't (it's waiting for a `timeupdate` event). Once the video has been playing it's working just as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The event to use is not "timeupdate", I think it is "seeked".
When you change the currentTime, first a "seeking" event happens then as soon as the video is in sync with the time chosen, the "seeked" event is triggered.

I tested this with Google 28 and it worked without needing a .play() + .pause() on the control.