# Can't get .on( 'timeupdate', 'video' ....) event to fire after inserting element dynamically

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation, event-listener, html5-video

I am dynamically adding a video element to the page with custom controls. All of my custom controls are working except for the 'timeupdate' event which I'm using to updated the seek bar position.

I've tried using:

```
 $(document).on('timeupdate', 'video', function () {
              alert("got it");            
        });
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770247/html5-video-timeupdate-event-not-firing) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to solve this with delegated events. [api.jquery.com/on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
I could fire other events fine when delegating from the document, but not on the video element itself. So I slept since then and it turns out the event bindings weren't taking hold because they were getting declared before the object existed. Solved it by adding the event bindings after the video element is created.

```
function(){
//add video element
...
//add bindings
}
```