# Manipulate dynamically created content when video time updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

I have an HTML5 video and I need to get some data from other elements that were dynamically created on "timeupdate", I am currently using:

```
var video = $('video');
video.on('timeupdate', function() {

    //get data from dynamically created elements

});
```

This only works with previously created elements, but once I introduce a dynamically created element it comes back as `undefined`, what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088565/cant-get-on-timeupdate-video-event-to-fire-after-inserting-element

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, and I can't reproduce it because you posted too little code. Please post more code to reproduce the problem, of even better: reproduce it in a jsFiddle so we can debug it.

Comment: how you create the dinamic content?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough code, but I think I understand correctly.

The problem is in video tag. Looks like you define sources like:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

So if you change sources video in `<source>` tag, you will get an old source or `undefined`.

The correct and working way to dinamically change video source is to change src attribute of `<video>` tag, for example:

```
$('#video').attr('src', new_source);
$('#video').get(0).play();
```